webr and gt - throws error - Error: 'browser' must be a non-empty character string
Playing around with Quarto and webr, I am a happy camper when tinkering around with other {tidyverse} packages, e.g. {ggplot2}.
The following works seamlessly:
Quarto yaml:

---
engine: knitr
filters:
  - webr
webr:
  packages: ['ggplot2']
---

and then as a (interactive) code-chunk in the rendered document
# note: the chunk label is "webred" with {webr-r}
ggplot(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, color = "blue", alpha = 0.5)

Applying this logic to {gt} and setting in the YAML packages: ['gt'] 
my_table <- mtcars[1:10,]   # subset to 10 rows
my_table |> gt()

The output is then: Error: 'browser' must be a non-empty character string.
Calling ?gt results in a standard (embedded) help page. Thus, the package {gt} appears to be loaded and available in the {webr} session.
Unfortunately, I could not find any documentation/example that shows how to combine {webr} and {gt}. Thanks for any pointer.

I've ran into this myself just recently, and we should be able to address this by specifying by using a chunk with the option resuls: asis and then printing using view = FALSE
#| results: asis
my_table |> gt() |> print(view = FALSE)

However, that causes an issue due to the maximum output size of WebR being triggered, as gt outputs a whole bunch of CSS. We can address that by chunking the output.
#| results: asis
fix_print <- function(characters, max_print = 100){
  i <- 1
  while(nchar(characters) >= i){
    cat(substring(characters, i, i + max_print ))
    i <- i + max_print + 1
  }
}
my_table |> gt() |> as_raw_html(inline_css = FALSE) |> fix_print()

